# Golang concurrency access to slice

Tags: go, concurrency

**My use case:**

- append `items`(small struct) to a `slice` in the main process
- every 100 items I want to process items in a `processor` go routine (then pop them from `slice`)
- items comme in very fast continuously

I read that if there is at least one "write" in more then two goroutines using a variable (`slice` in my case), one shall handle the concurrency (mutex or similar).

**My questions:**

- If I do not handle with a mutex the r/w on `slice` do I risk problems ? (ie. Item 101 arrives while the `processor` is working on 1-100s)
- What is the best concurrency technique for the incoming item flow to remain "fluent" ?

**Disclaimer:**

- I do not want any event queueing, I need to process items in a given "bundle" size

Answer (score 3):

Actually you don't need a lock here. Here is a working code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type myStruct struct {
    Cpt int
}

func main() {
    buf := make([]myStruct, 0, 100)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    // Main process
    // Appending one million times
    for i := 0; i < 10e6; i++ {
        // Locking buffer
        // Appending
        buf = append(buf, myStruct{Cpt: i})
        // Did we reach 100 items ?
        if len(buf) >= 100 {
            // Yes we did. Creating a slice from the buffer
            processSlice := make([]myStruct, 100)
            copy(processSlice, buf[0:100])
            // Emptying buffer
            buf = buf[:0]
            // Running processor in parallel
            // Adding one element to waitgroup
            wg.Add(1)
            go processor(&wg, processSlice)
        }
    }
    // Waiting for all processors to finish
    wg.Wait()
}

func processor(wg *sync.WaitGroup, processSlice []myStruct) {
    // Removing one element to waitgroup when done
    defer wg.Done()
    // Doing some process
    fmt.Printf("Procesing items from %d to %d\n", processSlice[0].Cpt, processSlice[99].Cpt)
}
```

A few notes about your problem and this solution:

- If you want a minimal stop time in your feeding process (e.g, to respond as fast as possible to a HTTP call), then the minimal thing to do is just the copy part, and run the processor function in a go routine. By doing so, you have to create a unique process slice dynamically and copying the content of your buffer inside it.
- The `sync.WaitGroup` object is needed to ensure that the last processor function has ended before exiting the program.

Note that this is not a perfect solution: If you run this pattern for a long time, and the input data comes in more than 100 times faster than the processor processes the slices, then there are going to be:

- More and more processSlice instances in RAM -> Risks for filling the RAM and hitting the swap
- More and more parallel processor goroutines -> Same risks for the RAM, and more to process in the same time, making each of the calls be slower and the problem gets self-feeding.

This will end up in the system crashing at some point.

The solution for this is to have a limited number of workers that ensures there is no crash. However, when this number of workers is fully busy, then there will be wait in the feeding process, which does not answer what you want. However this is a good solution to absorb a charge which intensity is changing in time.

In general, just remember that if you feed more data than you can process in the same time, your program will just reach a limit at some point where it can't handle it so it has to slow down input acquisition or crash. This is mathematical!

Comment: Allright this is very clear, many thanks ! I understand of course the math and I think this shall not be my problem (i'm already processing the items separatly at time).   Woud this be still the same if I added my items in separate routines ? With something like this : `go buf = append(buf, myStruct{Cpt: i})`

Comment: You'd have to have a mutex if you do that, and globally you'd loose a lot of performance because of the lock overhead compared to the simplicity of your action, and moreover you'd also have a lock when processing the buffer flush. I think here having the generation in a single thread is the most efficient.

Comment: Allright I see, I gota double check if the main thread is the only one feeding the items. One other thing that comes to my mind is passing items via a chanel, that way I could "simply" read them and pu them into a slice in the processor and process slice by slice at the processor(s) rate. But that would mean passing alot of data inter-thread and a colleague told me it sounds like a bad design. What do you think ?

Comment: I think that's you'd loose some performance compared to monothread, the same ways as you would with mutexes. However that would be simpler and clearer to write than with mutexes. If you have several feeders that would be a solution. You can also have an hybrid approach, accumulating data on feeder side and passing them to the feeder's buffer by batches (with a limit of size and time to trigger batch delivery. Some libraries like https://github.com/MasterOfBinary/gobatch can help with that.

Comment: No need to copy anything. Just hand off the original slice when it's full and then make a new one: https://go.dev/play/p/2N93upazFXX

Comment: You are right, this is clearer and more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. Indeed I like your suggestion too Peter. I checked and my feeding is actualy concurrent.. So I ought block item adding and the buffer process+refresh with a mutex I think...

Comment: This is a solution, otherwise if you don't care about processing order you can have one processor per input thread and 2 independent buffers. This way you don't have any concurrency issue.

Comment: Hmm not sure I can do that. I'll try this and will do some heavy testing :) Many thanks to you both !